# Логические операции над числами

Tags: java

Добрый день. Изучаю Java и появился такой вопрос:

Чему равна переменная x после выполнения следующей строки ?

```
int x = (-14) | 7;
```

Дело в том , что здесь правильным ответ оказался -9.

Я рассуждал так , в двоичной системе счисления 14 представляется как 1110. Но т.к. число 14 со знаком "-", то выходит, что нужно использовать дополнительный код. Выходит, что для числа 14 дополнительный код равен:

```
1110 ->0001(инвертируем все разряды)->0010(добавляем +1)->10010(Дописываем слева знаковый единичный разряд)
```

Теперь выполняем логическую операцию OR на двумя двоичными представлениями чисел:

```
10010     
+  
00111
```

и получается 10111 что в переводе в целое число приравнивается к 23. Объясните пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Вроде все по правилам, а результат все равно не правильный. Заранее Спасибо.

Comment: Делаете в рассуждения переход от чисел со знаком к числам без него. 10111 -- знак (1) и 0111 -> (в доп код) 1001 = 9. Так что всё нормально. А 23 при четырёх разрядах не бывает

Comment: То есть я правильно рассуждал . Просто когда получил число 10111 , то 1 в начале это его знак , а дальше идет само представление числа в дополнительном коде, которое нужно перевести в прямое представление в обратном порядке как делать обратный код. Так получается ?

Comment: Ну если Вы так представили -114, то да. Как Вам уже объяснили, знаковый разряд находится значительно левее, но все 32-4=28 разрядов в Вашем случае единички. Можно расписать их все, но ничего не изменится. Просто Вам было бы сложнее забыть о знаковом разряде.

Comment: То есть нужно записывать все 32 разряда в любом случае ? То есть если пример поменяется , то мои рассуждения уже не будут правильными ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас ошибка, вы неправильно представили число.. (не туда знаковый дописали) (тут я считаю что int==4байта (в java это верно, а вот C\C++ не факт))

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 0010 (-14)
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0111 (7)
```

выполняем OR

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 0111 (-9)
```

**UPD** (ответ на коммент: "Но как вы определили , что число 10111 представляется как -9")

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 0111//отрицательное число (-9)
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 0110//вычли 1
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 1001//инвертировали
```

или тоже самое

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 0111//отрицательное число (-9)
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 1000//инвертировали
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 1001//добавили 1
```

**UPD 2**

[статья по java и побитовым операциям](http://habrahabr.ru/post/187606/)

Comment: у меня тоже получилось число 10111 (у вас последние 5 знаков). Но как вы определили , что число 10111 представляется как -9 ?

Comment: @Drylozav дык дополнительный код. Инвертируете, прибавляете единичку, получаете 9

Comment: скажите , а вы написали "не туда знаковый дописали" можете объяснить , что вы имели в виду ?

Comment: Спасибо большое . Доступно объяснили . Только можете подсказать, где можно про это прочитать более детальнее ?

Comment: я не так выразился... я сразу представил в голове число в байтах (1,2,3 или 4 неважно) и потому сказал что не туда поставили,

в коментах выше вам уже сказали что ненадо было учитывать первый разряд (что привело бы к тому же результату)

Comment: @Drylozav а что именно детальнее? 

а то детальнее это и ASM и С++ и JAVA и ещё 100500 пудов информации.

Answer (score 1):

по правилам java, в подобных операциях числа приравниваются к int. А это 4 байта (32 бита).  А в Ваших рассуждениях этого не видно.

```
-14 => 11..110001
7   => 00..000111
```

результат логического или

```
    => 11..110111
```

Так как самый старший байт равен 1, то это отрицательное число. Поэтому и декодируем через дополнительное представление.

```
11..110111 => -00...001001 => -9
```

Comment: по правилам java, в подобных операциях числа приравниваются к int. Скажите, а где это про можно детальнее прочитать ?